# Vue js edit content according to its ID

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I’m starting with vue js and I’m listing some data from database. More specifically posts with title, description and images.

I have Edit and Delete buttons. All posts are loaded using `v-for`. So when I click to edit one post, all the posts are “openning” to be edited.

I need to open the editing only in one post at a time. I mean, the specific post I really want to edit.

I made some progress with title `input` and with image delete badge but still need to work on Save and Cancel buttons (they open in all posts) and input files (when I choose files in second post for example, they load into first post).

```
<div id="app" class="row mb-50">
   <div v-for="(item, index) in tours" v-bind:key="item.id" id="tours" class="col-md-12 mb-30">
      <div class="tour-list">
         <div class="tour-list-title">
            <p>

               <!-- here I can block input title to be disabled on other posts not than the specific one and I intend to do the same with textarea -->

               <input class="inputEdit" type="text" ref="item.id" v-model="item.title"
                  :disabled="editingTour !== item.id" :class="{inputEditOpen: !editingTour}" />
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="tour-list-description">
            <p>
               <textarea class="inputEdit" :disabled="!editingTour" v-model="item.description"
                  :class="{inputEditOpen: !editingTour}">
               {{ item.description }}
               </textarea>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="tour-list-pics">
            <div class="row mb-20">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <ul class="pics-list">
                     <li v-for="(image, index) in item.images">

                        <!-- here I could hide badge -->

                        <span :hidden="editingTour !== item.id" class="badge"
                           @click="$delete(item.images, index), deleteImage(image.imageID)">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="pics-list-image-container img-fluid cursor-pointer"
                           v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url(http://localhost/tours/'+image.image + ')' }"
                           @click="openModal = true, showModal(image.image)">
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li v-if="urls" v-for="(url, key) in urls" :key="key">
                        <div id="preview" :ref="'url'" class="pics-list-image-container img-fluid"></div>
                     </li>
                     <li v-if="editingTour" class="add-pics-item">
                        <div :hidden="editingTour !== item.id" class="mt-10">
                           <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
                           <img class="img-fluid" src="./img/plus-icon.png">
                           </label>
                           <input id="file-upload" type="file" @change="onFileChange"
                              name="files[]" multiple />
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tour-list-options">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <span>
                  <button @click="editingTour = item.id" v-if="!editingTour"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Edit</button>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                  <button  @click="editTour(item)" v-if="editingTour"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Save</button>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                  <button @click="clearInput" v-if="editingTour"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Cancel</button>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                  <button @click="deleteTour(item.id, index)" v-if="!editingTour"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Delete</buton>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

If I use

```
<button  @click="editTour(item)" v-if="editingTour == item.id" class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Save</button>
```

all others Save buttons get hidden.

Comment: I wouldn't think this would cause your infinite loop, but `v-if="editingTour = item.id"` <= is definitely a code smell as `=` is assignment, not equality.

Comment: Though, that could be your infinite loop issue, if changing that variable value causes your view generation to start over.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I changed to `v-if="editingTour == item.id"`. What happens now is that all others Save buttons get hidden. Trying to deal with that now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use add to each object of list new property `isEditing` and look for it in each item of the loop to check `Save`/`Edit` show.
Now your one prop `editingTour` can't be used for multiple edit, it can't store array of edited items id.
Template of buttons would look like:

```html
                  <span>
                  <button @click="item.isEditing = item.id" v-if="!item.isEditing"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Edit</button>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                  <button  @click="editTour(item)" v-if="item.isEditing"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Save</button>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                  <button @click="clearInput(item)" v-if="item.isEditing"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Cancel</button>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                  <button @click="deleteTour(item.id, index)" v-if="!item.isEditing"
                     class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Delete</button>
                  </span>
```

Comment: hi, I tested it but nothing happens. Should I have to change anything else?

Comment: Hi, yes, first of all you should add `isEditing` prop to all items of array, before its use. Then you should add methods for `click` events, and do changes there. Sorry, don't have much time to show you full solution.)

Comment: Ok. If you have time I'd appreciate your help.